# Remove unwanted characters from starting position

Tags: oracle

I need to remove only characters at the beginning.

```
GFG2014JP34343
D2013GH43422
HHH2014JP34343
CC2013GH43422
```

Output:

```
2014JP34343
2013GH43422
2014JP34343
2013GH43422
```

I tried REGEXP with different pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT val, REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '^[^[:digit:]]+', '') AS val_out
FROM yourTable;
```